# XCACHE - Problema xcache.mmap_path e xcache.coredump_directory

Tags: php, apache, xcache

Olá, estou instalando o XCACHE no meu servidor WHM. Estou colocando a configuração no meu php.ini, após salvar, comecei receber diversos emails root do servidor.

Comentando cada linha do codigo que coloquei no php.ini, descobrir que o problema estão nessas duas linhas:

```
xcache.mmap_path = "/tmp/_xcache"
xcache.coredump_directory = "/tmp/_phpcore"
```

Os emails que recebo, são todos relacionado ao CRON

> Assunto: Cron  php
>   /home/xxxxx/public_html/import-csv.php > /dev/null 2>&1
>
> Mensagem:
>   /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: line 1:     3 Segmentation fault
>   php /home/xxxxx/public_html/import-csv.php > /dev/null 2>&1

Outro email:

> Assunto: Cron  /usr/local/bin/php
>   /home/xxxxx/public_html/mediacp/scanner/cron.php auto=1 >/dev/null
>   2>&1
>
> Mensagem: /bin/bash: line 1: 25142 Segmentation fault
>   /usr/local/bin/php /home/xxxxx/public_html/mediacp/scanner/cron.php
>   auto=1 > /dev/null 2>&1

Imagem do phpinfo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]